# How did fig tree take root in trunk of palm tree?

Tags: ecology, plant-physiology, trees

Please see pictures below.

[image]

[image]

I never saw anything like this.  Do the roots of the  fig tree penetrate the trunk of the palm tree?  Is there a symbiotic relationship between the two?

Comment: I won't write an answer because I couldn't identify the small plant (whom you are telling as 'fig') so couldn't search its behaviors. However such association is called epiphytic relation. Epiphytes usually could be of various grades between  commensal (such as many orchids) to parasite(such as *Cuscuta*) Also at the crevices on tree-trunk, soil and rotten organic matters accumulate where non-epiphytic plants sometimes grow if somehow a seed reaches there.Some figs like *Ficus benghalensis* and *F. religiosa*  common example, of that incidence and may cover up and kill the host plant.